# How to show items which belong to the category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'd like to answer what I'm doing wrong. So, I'm trying to list all products that belong to the category, on the category's page. Here is the code:

```
    <% @product = Product.all%>
    <% @product.where("category_id = ?", params[:@category_id]).each do |product| %>
      <%= product.title %>
<%end%>
```

But there is nothing showing up on my page. So, what's wrong?

Comment: 1) `params[:category_id]` ; 2) it should be done in controller, not view.

Comment: Wow, where exactly in conroller? Sorry for stupid question.

Comment: what does your URI look like. eg `http://example.com?category_id=123`

Comment: you have to define an instance variable in controller's action, and then in view just use this variable in your loop. I assume, it is `index` action you have view for. If so, `def index @products = Product.all end` and then in view `@products.where(category_id: params[:category_id]).each...`. Also, Make sure you have in params what you expect (inspect the params if not sure).

Comment: My URL looks like: `http://example.com/categories/(id of category, ex.:1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a whole bunch of problems with your code.

1) [Read guides for starters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html).

2) You have to define an instance variable in controller's action, and then in view just use this variable in your loop. I assume, it is index action you have view for. If so,

```
def index
  # this variable will be used in view
  @products = Product.where(category_id: params[:id])
end
```

and then in view

```
@products.where(category_id: params[:category_id]).each..
```

**Also, Make sure you have in params what you expect (inspect the params if not sure).**

3) You do not execute code, so nothing is being output.

In erb to make things being evaluated you either use `-` or `=`. You used none of these. Here is how it should look like:

```
# notice dash at the beginning of the line
<%- @products.each do |product| %>
  <%= product.category_id %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I know!

Answer (score 0):

probably you want read `:category_id` from `params`, not `:@category_id` (so it should be `params[:category_id]`, not `params[:@category_id]`).

Comment: I changed it, but nothing has changed.